# direct_to_template equivalent for email?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-email

I'm writing a little shortcut function to basically do the same thing as `direct_to_template` for sending email:

```
from django.template import Context, loader, Template

def direct_to_email(to, subject, from_email, template_name, parameters):
    parameters = {} if parameters is None else parameters

    template = loader.get_template(template_name)
    context = Context(parameters)

    body = template.render(context)
    # ...etc.
```

How can I get my `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` to process this, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`render_to_string()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut) does that trick.

Comment: Fair enough, though I was able to make it work by passing a `RequestContext` as opposed to a regular context.